# Specifications for "disabled" icon on OS status bar

Tags: macos, cocoa, icons, png, statusbar

I'm trying to add 2 icons to the status bar: a normal one (black png with transparent background) and a "disabled" one when my app is idle.

I trie making the latter a gray png with transparent background, but it becomes invisible when added to the status bar.

How should I create the icon so it displays grayed out?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I haven't tried this, but what if you supply a single template image (which must be black-and-transparent) and set the `enabled` of the status item?

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me is:

`NSStatusBar.system.statusItem.button.appearsDisabled = true`